# How can my users log into my web app ?

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I have already placed my login form, installed and initialized the PHP SDK. 
Could someone link or find me a decent and basic guide to write the right code for this process? On the facebook's developer site there isn't much at all and it isn't explained in depth. I really don't know what to do.

Is there an holy good guy who is able to give me just a tiny little advice?

Answer (score 3):

Did you read https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/#login ? This is quite comprehensive and it suggests you use the JavaScript SDK for the authentication.

Comment: I read it 100 times, but it doesn't say what to do after placing the button.

Comment: on the URL that I posted above, it tells us that we should specify the redirect URL once the user logs in to the website. On the redirect url, you can use Facebook JavaScript API's additional methods like https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/ to see if the user is logged in, if so, show him hidden content, if not, show him the login screen.

Comment: Yes, do you know if it is possible to use the login button with the PHP SDK ?

Comment: I did it a long time ago but I do not remember the specifics, nor do I have the code with me now. I'll try and list down ways to go:

1. Go to http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/ and initialize the app with code provided on above URL.

2. Use http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-getUser/ to see if the user is logged in

3. Use http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-getLoginUrl/ if the user is not logged in. 

Important: Do read the above docs carefully to get the details